# Tick a checkbox using Selenium webdriver in Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

Fellows,

I'm doing some webscraping and need to download multiple PDFs from the www1.hkexnews.hk website.

However, I encountered a problem while trying to make my Selenium chromedriver **tick the box** that appears every time one wants to download a PDF on the said website. The code executes, but the box still appears unclicked.

Please refer to my source code below - would appreciate any advice!

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.maximize_window()

start_address = "https://www1.hkexnews.hk/app/appyearlyindex.html?lang=en&board=mainBoard&year=2021"

driver.get(start_address)
PDF_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Full Version')]")
print("Now clicking...'", PDF_link.text,"'")
PDF_link.click()

checkbox = driver.find_element_by_id('warning-statement-accept')
print("Now clicking...", checkbox.text)
checkbox.click
```

Edit: Thank you guys! The downloading works fine now, just one small follow-up question - how can I modify the downloading code to **save each PDF according to its company name** - available through `all_names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='applicant-name']")`?

At the moment, I am using the automatic download options as per below, I guess the downloading logic would have to be adjusted (I would rather download the PDFs with correct names already, rather than employ the dirty workaround of using Python to change their names once they're saved...)

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
"download.default_directory": "/Users/XXX/Downloads", #Change default directory for downloads
"download.prompt_for_download": False, #To auto download the file
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True #It will not show PDF directly in chrome
})
```

Comment: aren't you missing parenthesis? checkbox.click()

Comment: Apologies, when I add the parentheses, it returns an error: "Message: element not interactable". However, this element is clearly clickable and I can do it by hand - you can see for yourself on the website. Any idea how I can click on it using Selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://www1.hkexnews.hk/app/appyearlyindex.html?lang=en&board=mainBoard&year=2021"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

driver.get(link)
elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//tr[@class='record-ap-phip']//a[contains(.,'Full Version')]")))
elem.click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='warning-statement-dialog']//label[@for='warning-statement-accept']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='warning-statement-dialog']//a[contains(@class,'btn-ok')]"))).click()
```

Here goes the modified version of the script which will kick out the newly opened tabs. I didn't include the downloading logic within the script. I suppose you can do that yourself.

```
driver.get(link)
current = driver.current_window_handle
for elem in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//tr[@class='record-ap-phip']//a[contains(.,'Full Version')]"))):
    elem.click()
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='warning-statement-dialog']//label[@for='warning-statement-accept']"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='warning-statement-dialog']//a[contains(@class,'btn-ok')]"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.new_window_is_opened)
    driver.switch_to.window([window for window in driver.window_handles if window != current][0])
    print(driver.current_url)
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(current)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: This worked!!! Thank you so much!

On a side note - once I have saved this PDF, is there an efficient way to close the open PDF tab and begin searching for the next ***a[contains(.,'Full Version')]*** ?

If I do this for 1,000 PDFs, I don't want to crash my Chrome by leaving hundreds of PDF tabs open...

Comment: Please, check out the edit @gweilo8.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much!!

For the downloading logic I know how to include a simple one, but may I ask you how should the downloading code look if I need to save each PDF with the name of each company i.e. ***all_names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='applicant-name']")***?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

1. "checkbox" locator is wrong.
2. Your current code will download the first PDF file only.
   It is preferably to use expected conditions explicit waits instead of implicit wait.
   This should work better:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.maximize_window()

start_address = "https://www1.hkexnews.hk/app/appyearlyindex.html?lang=en&board=mainBoard&year=2021"

driver.get(start_address)
PDF_link = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Full Version')]")))

print("Now clicking...'", PDF_link.text,"'")
PDF_link.click()

checkbox = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[./label[@for='warning-statement-accept']]//input")))
print("Now clicking...", checkbox.text)
checkbox.click
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm afraid that the code which you have provided, while executing without error, still ***does not tick the tickbox***. 

Would you mind testing it on the website itself? I need to tick the tickbox, then the "accept" button and then download the PDF...

Comment: Are you sure this code doesn't select the checkbox? You still have to click the Accept button after that.

Comment: It does not :(((

Does it work on your browser? When I run the code, the tickbox remains blank and even after I physically click on the "Accept" button, nothing happens. 

Thus, the tickbox is clearly unclicked.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no Selenium with Python on my PC. Please see if the updated xpath will work for you